How to find eigen-pairs of Lie bracket?
For a field $\mathbb K$ and an $n\times n$-matrix $A$, we can define
$$L_A:\mathbb K^{n\times n}\to\mathbb K^{n\times n},X\mapsto[A,X]:=AX-XA$$
Soppose $(\lambda,v)$ is an eigen-pair of $A$, and $(\mu,w)$ is one for $A^T$,
then $L_A(vw^T)=Avw^T-v(A^Tw)^T=(\lambda-\mu)vw^T$.
We see that $\mathbb K^n\otimes\mathbb K^n\cong\mathbb K^n\otimes(\mathbb K^n)^*=\mathbb K^{n\times n}$, so for $V$, a $\lambda$-eigen-space of $A$, and $W$, a $\mu$-eigen-space of $A^T$, we deduce that $V\otimes W$ embeds into $\mathbb K^{n\times n}$ by $v\otimes w\mapsto vw^T$.
And if $A$ is diagonalizable (then so is $A^T$), then $\mathbb K^{n\times n}$ is a direct sum of $V\otimes W$ for eigen-spaces of $A,A^T$.
In this case, the $k$-eigen-space of $L_A$ is $\displaystyle\bigoplus_{\lambda-\mu=k}(V_\lambda\otimes W_\mu)$.
What if $A$ is not diagonalizable? Is the space I find enough? That is  in this case, are there some eigen-pair of $L_A$ having different form?

If your field is $\mathbb R$ eigenvalues doesnt have to exist. So your eigenspace decomposition is not the whole space in general (you can find easy counterexamples of $2\times 2$-matrices).

@TimonKolt Thank you for recommending me of the cases that the field is not algebraic closed, where there are eigen-values hiding in the extension. What if it is algebraic closed field like $\mathbb C$? Is there some other eigen-pairs for a non-diagonalizable matrix?

unfortunetly i dont know much about the eigen pairs of non diagonilizable matrices (in terms of your question...). But if your matrix is not conjugate to a diagonal matrix the sum of all eigen spaces is not the whole space. I found this article, it might help you: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Trigonalizable_element
